# How to build application without sudo privileges?

Tags: security, build, compiling, unprivileged

What do I need to setup on a Ubuntu 9.10 server so that a user can build applications of there choice (i.e. ./configure , make && make install) with out the need for sudo/admin privileges.

I just feel its a bit of a security risk having to give a user access to parts of the system they might not need in order to build a app.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your users use

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user/opt/
```

Or for cmake projects

```
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/user/opt/ ../source/
```

This will install the program in that prefix (instead of the default /usr/local/) and your users should then be able to run the program like this:

```
/home/user/opt/bin/program
```

If you want them to be able to run the programs by simply using the name (without full path) you need add `/home/user/opt/bin` to the path environment variable, edit the users .profile and add the following line:

```
export PATH=/home/user/opt/bin:$PATH
```

*Note that programs installed in this way will be private to the specific user, but it's a way to do it*

Comment: Other users will be able to use programs installed like this if they supply the full path and the permissions are set appropriately; and it appears that the default umask allows this on my desktop install.

Comment: The codebase I was compiling had a `Makefile` but no configure, I just went into it and changed the `prefix = /some/path` line to my own home directory (no trailing slash) and then ran `make install` without sudo - all working now, so thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Users can build applications without sudo rights. The only time you need sudo rights is when you want to install something into the system directories.

`./configure` and `make` work always without sudo rights. `make install` usually needs sudo rights because it will install the application to `/usr/local` or `/usr` (sometimes `/opt`).

However, if you change the prefix for the installation path (i.e. `./configure --prefix=~/usr/local`) in a way that the installation will be perform inside the user's home directory tree, no sudo rights are needed for `make install`.

Comment: I still think that your answer isn't completely backed up. Why do `./configure` and `make` work _always_ without `sudo`? How should I justify it to someone who keeps executing `sudo make install` for example?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what *txwikinger* has said, you might want to check also `fakeroot`, which gives an opportunity for building .deb packages with `dpkg` without needing elevated privileges. Of course, installing those will generally need sudo access.