# How can I install Okular on Ubuntu 12.04 without super user access?

Tags: 12.04, okular

I'm at university and would like to put some annotations in a `PDF`. Unfortunately, only Evince is installed, but that doesn't allow the creation of annotations.

I'd like to install `Okular`, but don't have super user access. I assume that I should be able to install it in my user directory without super user access, but don't know how to do it.

**Could someone please point out how I would have to go about to install Okular in my user directory without `sudo`?**

I did see [How to install programs into user directory without sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/577232/186129), but it just tells me that I can't use the `.deb`.

I've also seen [How to build application without sudo privileges?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2167/186129), but neither answer actually specifies what I should run `.configure` on. I assume some kind of source package, but the `.deb` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the apt-get source command to fetch the source of the package and configure it to install locally.

```
apt-get source okular
cd okular*
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Or using `cmake`:

```
cd okular*
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/maythux/opt/ ../okular-4.8.5/
```

---

You may be able to download the `.deb` of okular.

```
apt-get download okular
```

Once you have your  file run dpkg directly from the command line.

The following example will install okular.deb into your home directory.

```
dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HOME okular_*.deb
```

---

Comment: I ran `apt-get`, switched to the directory, but for the `./configure` it tells me "File not found". Any idea, what I am doing wrong? Do I have to create that file?

Comment: Try cmake for okular

Comment: Apparently, I am out of luck: `CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:98 (MESSAGE):
  ERROR: cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake not found in
  /home/<user>/.kde/share/apps;/usr/share/kde4/apps`.

Comment: dpkg tells me `dpkg: Fehler: Auf den Statusbereich von dpkg kann nicht zugegriffen werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden`, roughly translated "cannot access state area of dpkg: File not found". Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If installing Okular locally doesn't work, you could try downloading and Adobe Reader for Linux, and installing it locally. Instructions given on this site [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609924/to-view-the-full-contents-of-this-document-you-need-a-later-version-of-the-pdf/609933?noredirect=1#comment915226_609933).

Comment: Bit of broken window syndrom: You link to a question, which has an answer that links to an article that links a download. ;) Anyway, I tried, but directly trying to execute the `.deb` requires admin access, while trying the `dpkg -i --force-not-root --root=$HOME adbe_*.deb` as proposed by [Maythux](http://askubuntu.com/a/642250/186129) gives me the same error message as for trying to install from `okular.deb`.